# Drawing ROC plot for SDT in R

Tags: r, roc, signal-detection

I am trying to plot an ideal ROC plot as predicted by Signal Detection Theory.

Here are the formulas I try to plot:

```
hi = Φ((d′−ci)/σ) (3)
fi = Φ(−ci) (4) ￼
```

where d′ and σ are the mean and standard deviation of strength for old items, and ci is the criterial bound for the ith condition. The function Φ is the cumulative distribution.

Substituting (4) into (3) yields

`hi = Φ([d′ + Φ^−1(fi)]/σ).`

**Clarification:** The formulas above are from the following paper http://pcl.missouri.edu/sites/default/files/p_6.pdf on page 6. I would expect to get an ROC graph like Figure 1D (page 39 of the pdf).

My R code as far looks as follows:

```
c_i <- seq(0, 1, 0.001)
sigma <- 1.2
d <- 3

f_i <- pnorm(-c_i)
h_i <- pnorm((d+qnorm(f_i))/sigma)

plot(c_i, h_i, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
```

Unfortunately this doesn't give correct results. What am I missing?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Its difficult for us to figure out what you did wrong when we don't know what you are trying to do. Would you care to elaborate, or perhaps provide a link to what you are trying to show?

Comment: I added a link to the paper I used. I am trying to recreate Figure 1D on page 39. Explanations are on page 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse of the distribution function is not simply taking the terms to the -1 power (this is kind of an abuse of notation). Consider $x^2$. The inverse of $x^2$ is $\sqrt{x}$ NOT $1/x^2$.

The inverse of the normal CDF can be calculated in R using `qnorm`.

This is probably what you want:

```
sigma <- 1.2
d <- 3

f_i <- seq(0, 1, 0.001)
h_i <- pnorm((d+qnorm(f_i))/sigma)

plot(f_i, h_i, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have changed it in the R code above. It's still not giving the expected results. Do you see any more errors?

Comment: note that `qnorm(pnorm(-c_i))` is redundant, you can just put c_i. This makes me think there might be something wrong with your derivation.